# missing select options with Sweet Alert

Tags: sweetalert

This may be a ServiceNow issue, but I added a Sweet Alert to show a select box just so I can gather a value to pass on to the next record... but the select box is not showing, the popup is there just no box or options.  What am I missing?  Screenshot:
[Select Box Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfrgK.png)

Thanks so much, super frustrated with something I thought would be simple to add :)

```js
swal({
  title: 'Select Outage Tier',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: {
    '1': 'Tier 1',
    '2': 'Tier 2',
    '3': 'Tier 3'
  },
  inputPlaceholder: 'required',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: function (value) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (value !== '') {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject('You need to select a Tier');
      }
    });
  }
}).then(function (result) {
  swal({
    type: 'success',
    html: 'You selected: ' + result
  });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Your code snippet is for [SweetAlert**2**](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) and most probably your issue is that you're including the original unmaintained [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) plugin, which doesn't have the select-box support.

Your code works just fine with included SweetAlert2 library:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Select Outage Tier',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: {
    '1': 'Tier 1',
    '2': 'Tier 2',
    '3': 'Tier 3'
  },
  inputPlaceholder: 'required',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: function (value) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (value !== '') {
        resolve();
      } else {
        resolve('You need to select a Tier');
      }
    });
  }
}).then(function (result) {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'success',
      html: 'You selected: ' + result.value
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: You will need to call fire, e.g. `swal.fire({ ...`  to get it to work on sweetalert2 see https://sweetalert2.github.io/#usage

Comment: @Limon Monte it was informative. I do have a question in regards combination of the label and input options. Can you please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65566877/align-label-and-select-dropdown-in-the-same-row-in-the-sweetalert-2

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this block after change it,

```
   var span = document.createElement("span") 

    span.innerHTML = '<div class="dropdown"> 

         <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example                            
           <span class="caret"></span></button>                     
   <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
<li><a href="#">HTML</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>                         
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>                  
    </ul>
```

```
    swal({
        title: "Rapor Alacak Yetkili ",
        text: "Rapor Almak İçin Onaylayınız",
        icon: "info",
        confirmButtonText: "Kaydet",
        cancelButtonText: 'İptal',
        content: span,
        buttons: ["İptal", "Tamam"],

    }).then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            Kullanici = $("#swaladi").val() + " " + $("#swalsoyadi").val()

            var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
            win.focus();
        } else {
            swal("Rapor Alma İptal Edilmiştir.");
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `preConfirm()`  methods and `showValidationMessage()` did the job,  do not forget to reset validations.Hope this will help.

````
  title: 'Select Outage Tier',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: {
    '1': 'Tier 1',
    '2': 'Tier 2',
    '3': 'Tier 3'
  },
  inputPlaceholder: 'required',
  showCancelButton: true,
   preConfirm: (value) => {
        if (!value) {
          Swal.showValidationMessage(
            '<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> You need to select a Tier'
          );
        }else{
    /**Reset validation**/
           Swal.resetValidationError();
    }

   
      },
}).then(function (result) {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'success',
      html: 'You selected: ' + result.value
    });
  }
})```


  [1]: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples
````

Answer (score 0):

```
  const { value: fruit } = await Swal.fire({
  title: "Select field validation",
  input: "select",
  inputOptions: {
    Fruits: {
      apples: "Apples",
      bananas: "Bananas",
      grapes: "Grapes",
      oranges: "Oranges"
    },
    Vegetables: {
      potato: "Potato",
      broccoli: "Broccoli",
      carrot: "Carrot"
    },
    icecream: "Ice cream"
  },
  inputPlaceholder: "Select a fruit",
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: (value) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (value === "oranges") {
        resolve();
      } else {
        resolve("You need to select oranges :)");
      }
    });
  }
});
if (fruit) {
  Swal.fire(`You selected: ${fruit}`);
}
```

reference document: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#inputOptions

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**