# sweetalert v1 - put select box inside sweetalert 1

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

Im trying to get `select` box inside sweetalert (version 1), Now it goes work, if I use sweetalert2, but the other function goes wrong! Like input form and design. So all i can do is, to make input of select to work in version 1. Is it possible? My code sample here :

```
function listUsersInSwal(merchantId){    
var usersList = ['user1','user2','user3'];
swal({
    title: "Message ",
    text: "Enter Message:",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    animation: "slide-from-top",
    input: 'select',
    inputOptions: usersList
})}
```

Comment: Show us code – https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This might help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266673/missing-select-options-with-sweet-alert

Comment: @MyTwoCents : Thanks for link.. Is it possible to achieve this in v1?